# JQuery If/Else show 1 field and hide the other field

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys I have 2 fields ( 1 text field , and the other is text_area field ).

if user clicks the text field, the text_area field will be hidden and vice versa. How should i do it ? I tried the JQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                 if($("#accession_number").click(function() 
                      {
                        $("#FASTA").hide();
                      })
                 );
                 else if($("#FASTA").click(function()
                      {
                        $("#accession_number").hide();
                      })
                    );
            });
```

But this doesn't seems to work. Can any1 help me ? 
Following are the interface:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `if` and `else` part of your code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#accession_number").click(function () {
        $("#FASTA").hide();
    });
    $("#FASTA").click(function () {
        $("#accession_number").hide();
    });
});
```

When you use:

```
$("#accession_number").click(function ...
```

...it binds a click "handler" function to the control; that function will be called later if the user clicks the control.

Might I suggest that hiding these fields on click of the other provides a poor user experience though, because if the user clicks one by mistake and hides the other they can't get the other back...

Comment: Hi i did think of that but i'm trying to figure how to hide 1 and show 1 first ><... I'm planning to put text, so that the user can click the text and the msitaken 1 will be hidden the correct 1 will show after that

Answer (score 2):

it should be

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#accession_number").click(function() {
        $("#FASTA").hide();
    })

    $("#FASTA").click(function() {
        $("#accession_number").hide();
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**in html**

```
<input class"test" value="">

<textarea class"test" ></textarea>
```

**in JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".test").click(function(){

$(".test").hide();
$(this).show();
});
});
```

reference

[show](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

[hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)